# event.latLng returns latitude and longitude, however, I can't extract just lat or lng

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Whenever I click on google map, I can extract the clicked location's latitude and longitude in bundle using `event.latLng`. Now, I need to actually insert the latitude and longitude into Google's geocoding API, however, I can't figure out how to extract just the latitude and longitude so I can insert them into the URL using string concatenation. The URL should look like this:

```
const latLng = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + 42 + ',' + 24 + '&key=secret'
```

Where the numbers 42 and 24 have to be replaced with the lat and lng values from event.latLng. I tried using `event.latLng.lat` and `event.latLng.lng` but I don't get the values.

Console.logging event.latLng shows something that I don't fully understand:

[image]

Comment: As your image shows, `lat` and `lng` are both of type `f()`, functions, so they need a pair of brackets `()` after them.

Comment: That did work, thanks. Wanna put it as answer so I can select it?

Comment: It's a dup, so according to the rules I shouldn't post an answer!